# underscores use of the article element on the page template

Tags: theme-development, themes

I understand and what I have seen the most is the use of the article element for blog/news posts. This makes total sense to me. article element to be used for content that can stand alone or syndicated.

However, when looking at the underscores starter theme it uses the  element to contain the content on Pages as well. For example:

```
<main>
<article>

//content here

</article>
</main>
```

Where what I have seen the most and what I would likely do is something like:

```
<main>
<section> (or div)

//content here

</section> (or end div)
</main>
```

Which is more correct, or possibly more flexible? I was thinking that some things that go on a page might not qualify as an article..? For example you may build out a layout using short codes. Would all that belong in an  article element?

Comment: This is about html5, not wordpress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. By definition

> The [article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-article-element) element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g., in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

> The [section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-section-element) element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content.

> [**Note 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-article-element) Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element.

So, if the `content here` is related stuffs but isn't completeness, wrap them inside `section` element. If the `content here` is a related stuffs and is completeness, wrap them inside `article` element.

Then, in the context of original [_s](https://github.com/Automattic/_s) theme, `article` is more correct.

#### 2. By flexibility

> [article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-article-element) elements are nested, the inner article elements represent articles that are in principle related to the contents of the outer article. For instance, a blog entry on a site that accepts user-submitted comments could represent the comments as article elements nested within the article element for the blog entry.

For `section` element, the content of inner `section` element doesn't relate to the content of the outer `section` element.

> **[Note 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-article-element)** When used specifically with content to be redistributed in syndication, the article element is similar in purpose to the entry element in Atom. [RFC4287](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/references.html#biblio-rfc4287)
>
> [**Note 2**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-article-element) The [schema.org microdata vocabulary](https://schema.org/Article) can be used to provide the publication date for an article element, using one of the CreativeWork subtypes.

The `section` element has more [aria role attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#aria-role-attribute) than `article` element.

So, which's more flexible? None, it depends on the content inside each element and [the context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#article-or-section?) they're in.

Bonus from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp):

> Newspaper: The sports **articles** in the sports **section**, have a technical **section** in each **article**.

Comment: Thank you. Yes more HTML 5, but I posted in Wordpress because I thought it involved how you template and create structure in a theme .